# bonding virtual network interfaces in ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, networking, kernel, ethernet, network-bonding

I have one physical interface(**eth0**) and two virtual interfaces(**eth0:1, eth0:2**) , both of virtual interfaces have Public IP addresses. I want to bond these two virtual interfaces into `bond0`, As you can see `/etc/network/interfaces` :

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 144.yy.xx.124
        netmask 255.255.255.224
        network 144.yy.xx.96
        broadcast 144.yy.xx.127
        gateway 144.yy.xx.109
        dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 4.2.2.2 4.2.2.4

auto eth0:1
allow-bond0 eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
        address 148.aa.bb.197
        netmask 255.255.255.248
        bond-master bond0
        bond-primary eth0:1

auto eth0:2
allow-bond0 eth0:2
iface eth0:2 inet static
        address 148.cc.dd.198
        netmask 255.255.255.248
        bond-master bond0


auto bond0
iface bond0 inet static
    address 10.31.1.5
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 10.31.1.0
    gateway 10.31.1.254
    bond-slaves none
    bond_mode balance-rr
    bond_miimon 100
    bond_downdelay 200
    bond_updelay 200
```

But when try to `sudo ifup bond0`, it returns:

```
Waiting for a slave to join bond0 (will timeout after 60s)
No slave joined bond0, continuing anyway
```

Also I added `bonding` in `/etc/modules`

UPDATE: I also tried this configuration for [/etc/network/interfaces](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11980915/) : http://paste.ubuntu.com/11980915/ But it has same problem.

Is it Interface bonding possible for virtual interfaces?
Whats the problem?

Comment: Why do you need to bond a virtual interface?. The whole idea of bonding is to combine two  ethernet cards into one to get increased bandwidth. If the virtual interface is sharing a ethernet card then your not going to get any increase in bandwidth. Another reason to bond two interfaces is reliability. With LACP properly configured on the switch, the network connection will stay up even if one interface goes down. Admittedly this makes more sense when the interfaces are on separate cards.

Comment: I want to change source ip address round robin.

Comment: Public bug reported:  "Using ifup on a master interface will call ifup for all slaves that are flagged with allow-bondX. (bondX being replaced by the master interface name). This will allow for extra setup for special slave interfaces."  https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/foundations-bugs/2012-June/097860.html

Answer (score 1):

To bond two virtual interfaces `eth0:1` and `eth0:2`, to create an auto failover interface, try this:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

To enable bonding You must install the `ifenslave` package:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ifenslave
```

To configure it, You must modify the `/etc/network/interfaces` file:

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

In the open file modify the followings lines:

```
auto bond0

iface bond0 inet static
    address 10.31.1.5
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 10.31.1.0
    gateway 10.31.1.254
    slaves eth0:1 eth0:2
    bond_mode active-backup
    bond_miimon 100
    bond_downdelay 200
    bond_updelay 200
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>, save file. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, close nano.

Comment: I also tried your configuration for /etc/network/interfaces(http://paste.ubuntu.com/11980915/) But it has same problem.